# Getting the raster file of elevation UK with 1 km grid?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, elevation

I am trying to get raster file of elevation UK with 1 km grid? The EU-DEM has an elevation of 30 meters and 25-meter grids. I could not find any source for 1 km.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Aggregate the 25m grid to 1km?

Answer (score -1):

[GDAL](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) can resample the 25m EU-DEM to an exact 1km grid:

```
gdal_translate -tr 1000 1000 -r nearest eu_dem_v11_E30N30.TIF E30N30_1km.tif
```

There are also other elevation datasets with coarser resolutions, like [1.8km ETOPO1](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/) or [1km SRTM](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/srtm30-global-1-km-digital-elevation-model-dem-version-11-land-surface). However these datasets aren't provided in equal area projections, so the size of each grid cell (measured in metres) will vary with latitidue.